# Live Peer to Peer Swarm

Tags: p2p, upnp, nat-traversal

If I have a client application running on multiple internet connections (behind routers and such) who connect to a server. Lets say there are 5, and 3 of them are told about the existence of each other by the server, could those 3 connect to each other so that when one of them sends a message, the other two receive it, and all this would be done without the first server or the other two clients sending or receiving any information, just the 3 clients connected to each other? How could they get past the routers and firewalls? Hope that makes sense.

**Edit**

In a sense, create a small private network between the 3 clients that talk directly to each other, not via the server (unless absolutely necessary). perhaps via another client with sufficient bandwidth and if its open to connections

Comment: This isn't really a C# question...

Comment: really? I thought I saw somewhere that WCF could do something like that. Besides, the xbox system works well, and thats in a c# derivative

Comment: WCF has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue what you wrote :), but that could probably help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700336.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WPFWCF_Chat_App_via_P2P.aspx

Comment: yeah, i had a peak at that one before, but does that do sufficient tunneling to create a connection between routers, or does netPeerTcpBinding still connect to an external server. Plus, how does it do name resolution for the specified binding address (i.e. "net.p2p://WPFChatMesh/rolandrodriguez.net/wpfchat" pointing to a specific set of clients. is there a public microsoft server somewhere that deals with all that)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: not always. There are cases where it is not possible for two peers located behind different NATs to communicate directly. They must go through a central peer with a public IP address.